# Armadillo -> Sparse matrix with repeated (translated) rows

Tags: matrix, armadillo

Is there an optimal way of using such a construct? Let `M` be a matrix

```
xx0000...

00xx00...

0000xx...
```

Forgive the `ASCII` description of the matrix, I could not get latex to work.

I am dealing with huge matrices, so an optimization is needed. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a matrix is called a [band(ed) matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) (Yours is upper triangular as well). Armadillo doesn't have built-in support for them, but you could store it as a sparse matrix or as a 2 by n dense matrix (and roll your own operations).

You could try using another library, I've used band matrices in FLENS. See [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/flens/examples/lapack-gbtrs.html) for an example.